# I cannot introduce a variable in midle of my function

Tags: php, html

**How can I make this work?**

```
mkdir("../USERS/" . $userIDforDir . "/PAGES")
```

Thanks.

The variable is:

```
$userIDforDir=$_SESSION['userID'];
```

And this is the error:

> Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\WIKILOAD\makePage\index.php on line 33

Comment: This should work, can you show us what the variable is please?

Comment: Have you instantiated the variable?

Comment: This may well be a permissions issue - usually Apache does not have write permissions into user directories.

Comment: I already updated onmy original question. And no is not and permission error, its work fine with out this variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the `$recursive` parameter. This will allow the creation of nested directories.

```
mkdir("../USERS/" . $userIDforDir . "/PAGES", 0755, true);
```

[PHP Manual: mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: @BorisDetry Glad I could help. Mark it as an answer so others know your question is answered.